# Redux | Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined which is my payload

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

Im getting an error that points to my reducer file. The response of the request seems to be ok, I logged the response in this is what i get:

Object {data: Object, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…}
config
:
Object
data
:
Object
hasMoreResults
:
true
searchResults
:
Array(10)
**proto**
:
Object
headers
:
Object
request
:
XMLHttpRequest
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
**proto**
:
Object

Actions file:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { FETCH_USERS, FETCH_USER } from './types';

const BASE_URL = "http://api_address/member-search"
export function fetchUsers(id,first_name, last_name, dob) {
  const request = axios.post(${BASE_URL}?patientId=${id}&firstName=${first_name}&lastName=${last_name}&dateOfBirth=${dob}&length=10).then(function (response){
  });
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERS,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

Reducer file

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import {
  FETCH_USERS, FETCH_USER
} from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.data.id]: action.payload.data };
    case FETCH_USERS:
      return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data, 'id');
  }

  return state;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong as long as I understand it seems that my payload is not being defined. But I got the payload in the actions file. Any help will be appreciated!.

Comment: If I remove the **.then function** the error dissapears. I think my error here is how am i receiving the data. I think I have to format it. Like in ajax when you do the   `var jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(data); var response = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);` 
Is there a way to do that here?

Comment: if you don't return anything from `then`, you are basically swallowing `response`. It would  work with `.then(response => { return response; })`.

Comment: Yes! You are correct thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { FETCH_USERS, FETCH_USER } from './types';

const BASE_URL = "http://api_address/member-search"
export function fetchUsers(id,first_name, last_name, dob) {
  const request = axios.post(${BASE_URL}?patientId=${id}&firstName=${first_name}&lastName=${last_name}&dateOfBirth=${dob}&length=10).then(function (response){
  // put this inside the "})" 
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERS,
    payload: request
  };
  });
}
```

I believe fixing the syntax error will help. Otherwise, the function will return before the response returns and `request` will be undefined.

Comment: I didnt work, if i remove the **.then function** the error goes away

Comment: Can you print the response and paste a bit of it here?

Comment: Object {data: Object, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…} config : Object data : Object hasMoreResults : true searchResults : Array(10) proto : Object headers : Object request : XMLHttpRequest status : 200 statusText : "OK" proto : Object  
**thats the response**